# Obtain a subset of tuple array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift2

I have a array of tuples like the following

```
var customProducts = [(productType: String, info:[String:AnyObject?])]
```

The parameter "productType" works like a "product category", like fruits, grains, beverage, etc.

The parameter "info" is a dictionary of nutritional information of the product.

I want to get a subset of the tuples array, based on the productType so I could obtain just the "info" dictionary for an specific productType. In C# I would try something like the following using Linq:

```
var fruits = customProducts.Where(q=>q.productType == "fruit").Select(q => q.info) as List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;
```

How may I archive the same results using Swift (2.x)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Swift equivalent would be:

```
let fruits = customProducts.filter { $0.productType == "fruit" }.map { $0.info }
```

Here `fruits` is `[[String : AnyObject?]]`, an array of dictionaries (an array of `info`, the same as your `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Worked exactly like I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method

```
let beverageInfo = (customProducts.filter { $0.productType == "Beverage" }).first?.info
```

Now `beverageInfo` is `[String : AnyObject?]?`, an optional dictionary representing the info for "Beverage" tuple.

Comment: Does the "first" property works like the "First()" method in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You should filter the array according to what type the product is

Eg

```
var customProducts = [(productType: String, info:[String:AnyObject?])]

let fruitProducts = customProducts.filter { product in 
    if product.productType == "fruit" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}.map { $0.info }
```

Then you can use fruitProducts however you want.

Comment: Your if statement has the following logic: If condition returns true, return true. If condition returns false, return false. You can just return `product.productType == "fruit"` ;)

Comment: Yeah you are right, I'm still relatively new to coding (4/5 months) so the way I right it is verbose but makes more sense to me. I'll try to be more concise in future. Thank you for the tip!